# How to get first parent node that has a boolean property in Umbraco 7

Tags: c#, lambda, umbraco, umbraco7

In a partial view macro, I'm trying to get the first ancestor or self node that contains a property called "breakInheritance" and has the value of `True`.  I've been attacking this statement / query for about an hour now while hunting around SO and the Our.Umbraco forums but I'm afraid I'm not getting anywhere.  I feel like this should be pretty straight forward.

**Query**

```
var nodeToUse = CurrentPage.AncestorOrSelf(x => (x.HasProperty("breakInheritance") && x.GetPropertyValue<bool>("breakInheritance")));
```

The lambda expression is underlined in red and says - `Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type`

I've found tons of resources on this error, but in all the cases that I've seen, it's someones custom extension method that they can just edit, so it hasn't really helped me too much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say it's better not to mix the [strongly typed API](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Querying/IPublishedContent/Collections) with the [dynamic API](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Querying/DynamicPublishedContent/Collections). In your code, you can either do `CurrentPage.AncestorsOrSelf` or `Model.Content.AncestorsOrSelf()`, with the first example clearly not accepting a lambda expression, as the error message indicates.

Try the following instead:

```
var node = Model.Content.AncestorsOrSelf()
                        .FirstOrDefault(n => n.HasProperty("breakInheritance") && 
                                             n.GetPropertyValue<bool>("breakInheritance"))
```

Comment: This is great, thanks for the tips.  I also had no idea that you could pass in a lambda expression to the FirstOrDefault() extension method.

Comment: You're welcome. Another trick is to pass the document type alias to `AncestorsOrSelf("docTypeAlias")`, which could allow you to filter based on the document type rather than using `.HasProperty()`. It might not always possible, but I prefer this because property names/aliases generally change more often than document types.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the desired behavior by casting the AncestorsOrSelf Method to `IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>`

```
var nodeToUse = ((IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>)CurrentPage
    .AncestorsOrSelf())
    .Where(x => (x.HasProperty("breakInheritance") && x.GetPropertyValue<bool>("breakInheritance") && x.HasValue("widgets")))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```